# Weird .astimezone behavior

Tags: python, pytz

I am doing some timezone conversions, and I get really weird results. Basically converting between timezones that differ only by whole hours, I still get non-whole results. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

datetime(2013, 12, 27, 20, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone('Europe/Bucharest'))\
    .astimezone(timezone('Europe/Berlin')).replace(tzinfo=None)
```

gives me

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 27, 19, 16)
```

(time difference between Bucharest and Berlin is 1 hour, so I should get 19:00 - instead I get 19:16)

I'm probably missing something really obvious, but I can't figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read the comments under the accepted answer to see why it is incorrect!  See the other answer instead! https://stackoverflow.com/a/45890531/1000655

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As specified by the [pytz documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#example-usage):

> Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones.

Indeed, this is not the expected result, the timezone is wrong:

```
>>> datetime(2013, 12, 27, 20, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone('Europe/Bucharest'))
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 27, 20, 0,
    tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Bucharest' BMT+1:44:00 STD>)
```

This is explained the `pytz` constructor given the `timezone('Europe/Bucharest')` timezone does not check *when* the timezone offset should be considered, and these things tend to change over time. `pytz` just uses the earlier known definition, which will often be wrong:

```
>>> timezone('Europe/Bucharest')
<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Bucharest' BMT+1:44:00 STD>
```

It looks like this timezone was used [until 1931](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=49&year=1931).

There is no such issue when working with UTC times and converting those using `astimezone` (for display purposes only as recommended):

```
>>> datetime(2013, 12, 27, 20, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)\
    .astimezone(timezone('Europe/Bucharest')) 
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 27, 22, 0,
    tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Bucharest' EET+2:00:00 STD>)
```

Then you get the expected result:

```
>>> datetime(2013, 12, 27, 20, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)\
    .astimezone(timezone('Europe/Bucharest'))\
    .astimezone(timezone('Europe/Berlin'))\
    .replace(tzinfo=None)
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 27, 21, 0)
```

Comment: @ibz: the correct call is `pytz.timezone('Europe/Bucharest').localize(datetime(2013, 12, 27, 20), is_dst=None)` as said at the very beginning of [pytz docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#introduction). It is wrong to use `pytz.utc` if input date is in Bucharest timezone.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian yup, I realized that later on. The answer is wrong, because it creates a UTC time and translates that in my desired initial timezone. Which is really not the same as creating a time in my desired initial timezone! Please consider adding another answer if you care about this reputation thing. ;)

Comment: Still I think this is weird behaviour

Comment: @ibz: Could you select the other answer, now that it exists?  I the big check mark and the ten votes may mislead people!

Comment: I *think* the big check mark and the ten (now nine) votes may mislead people :)

Answer (score 8):

I came across this same issue today, and eventually solved it using the answer @jfs put in the comment of the currently accepted answer. To help anyone else finding this in the future, here is a quick example of what does and doesn't work:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

naive = datetime.now()
la_tz = pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")

# this doesn't work
with_tz = naive.replace(tzinfo=la_tz)
converted_to_utc = with_tz.astimezone(pytz.utc)
print(converted_to_utc)

# this does work
with_tz = la_tz.localize(naive)
converted_to_utc = with_tz.astimezone(pytz.utc)
print(converted_to_utc)
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris, That works. My case is from utc to other tz.