# In python, how do I create a timezone aware datetime from a date and time?

Tags: python, django, timezone

In Python, let's say I have a date of 25 December 2016.  How can I create a timezone-aware datetime of noon on that date?

Bonus points if it's compatible with Django's timezone handling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: How to make a datetime object aware of the timezone in which it was created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108634/django-how-to-make-a-datetime-object-aware-of-the-timezone-in-which-it-was-crea)

Comment: This is specifically about getting a datetime from a date, rather than from a preexisting naive datetime.

Comment: You can `combine` the date with `time(0, 0)` to get the naive datetime

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The trick is to first `combine` the naive time and the date into a naive datetime. This naive datetime can then be converted to an aware datetime.

The conversion can be done using the third party package `pytz` (using, in this case, the 'Europe/London' timezone):

```
import datetime
import pytz

naive_time = datetime.time(0, 30)
date = datetime.date(2016, 12, 25)
naive_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(date, naive_time)

timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
aware_datetime = timezone.localize(naive_datetime)
```

If you're doing it in Django, and want to use the current timezone (as configured in Django), you can replace the final two lines with a call to `make_aware`:

```
from django.utils import timezone

aware_datetime = timezone.make_aware(naive_datetime)
```

Comment: [use `.localize()` method for timezones with a non-fixed utc offset](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36462784/4279). Or `django.utils.timezone.make_aware()`.

Comment: If datetime/time object is already created then use: `date_object.replace(tzinfo=timezone.get_current_timezone())`

Comment: @d345k0: `replace()` is a recipe for problems!  Use `localize()` instead, as jfs said.  `replace()` doesn't take the date into account when converting the timezone, so you get issue when the timezone has had transitions such as daylight savings (or other transitions... see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804837/weird-astimezone-behavior) )

Comment: As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52734072/1000655), `datetime.combine()` doesn't take the date into account when dealing with the timezone, leading to incorrect results.  As jfs said, use `timezone.localize()` instead! To be more specific, use combine without a timezone, and then use localize.

Comment: I should be more clear, in case someone stumbles across this: This answer is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks @NealGokli for pointing this out. I've now corrected the answer based on your comments.

Answer (score 5):

Erik's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52733868) explains why you should use `datetime.combine()` followed by `timezone.localize()`.  Setting the timezone directly on the datetime.time instance will not take the date into account, which could leave you with an incorrect result (due to daylight savings or even historic transitions).  `datetime.combine()` just isn't that smart!

```
>>> import pytz
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.date(2016, 12, 25)
>>> t = datetime.time(12)
>>> tz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
>>> tz.localize(datetime.datetime.combine(d,t))
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 25, 12, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
```