# How to make datetimes timezone aware and convert timezones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pytz

I have 3 dataframes with multiple columns, with 2 of them having a datetime that is is UTC, and the other one being 'Europe/Amsterdam'. However, they are still unaware.

How do I make these datasets timezone aware, and convert the 'Europe/Amsterdam' to UTC?

The datetimes are in the index of each dataset.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dataset" in this context?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623786/in-python-how-do-i-create-a-timezone-aware-datetime-from-a-date-and-time/36623787

Comment: Maybe should have said dataframe with multiple columns instead.

Comment: I don't really understand how to use that other thread, I'm dealing with dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pandas Dataframes and Python 3, you can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

values = {'dates':  ['20190902101010','20190913202020','20190921010101'],
          'status': ['Opened','Opened','Closed']
          }

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = ['dates','status'])

df['dates_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

df['dates_datetime_tz'] = df.dates_datetime.dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')

print (df)
print (df.dtypes)
```

Result:

```
            dates  status      dates_datetime         dates_datetime_tz
0  20190902101010  Opened 2019-09-02 10:10:10 2019-09-02 15:40:10+05:30
1  20190913202020  Opened 2019-09-13 20:20:20 2019-09-14 01:50:20+05:30
2  20190921010101  Closed 2019-09-21 01:01:01 2019-09-21 06:31:01+05:30
```

I've converted from UTC to a specific TZ, you can choose any other you need.